# How to create Mat from file bytes

Tags: java, opencv

I notice that `Highgui.imread("h:/opencv.jpg")` will automatically create the Mat instance with the correct type through auto-detection regardless of the file extensions.

Now what i have is a byte array uploaded from network.
Is it possible to create the correct Mat object without having to manually construct it with the row, col and type ?
I think this should be doable since `imread` can read the file bytes and detect the type, why not with the file bytes that i can pass ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your bytes are actual *pixels* :

```
Mat m = new Mat(h,w,type);
m.put(0,0,bytes);
```

if it is an encoded image (like 'on-disk'), headers and all:

```
Mat m = Highgui.imdecode(new MatOfBytes(bytes), 1);
```

[docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imdecode)

Comment: Works great, thanks alot ! I tried this approach previously with Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED (-1), but failed.